# Using $oid with MongoDB Atlas, Data API and updateMany

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to run an `updateMany` command with the Mongo Atlast Data API, but I can't figure out how to use $oid against an array of _ids. The workaround I landed on was

```
filter: { $or: _ids.map(_id => ({ _id: { $oid: _id } })) },
```

Is there a way to get a variation on one of these to work, though?

```
filter: { _id: { $in: { $map: { input: _ids, as: "$oid" } } } },
// or
filter: { _id: { $in: { $oid: _ids } } },
```

Comment: `_ids.map` is run client side before sending to the server, `$map` would only run server-side in an aggregation, not in a simple filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client side, convert the array of strings, then test with $in:

```
filter: { _id: {$in: _ids.map(_id => ( {$oid: _id} )) }}
```